# 伸{の}びる versus 延{の}びる in a JLPT question

Tags: word-choice, jlpt

In my JLPT workbook, it gives these examples to explain the difference between `延{の}びる` and `伸{の}びる`:

> 髪{かみ}は[１]{いっ}か[月]{げつ}に１センチぐらい伸{の}びる。
>
> 会議{かいぎ}はいつも30分{ぷん}ぐらい延{の}びる。

They both mean "stretch", more or less, so I assumed the difference was that `延{の}びる` was more about time and space, and `伸{の}びる` is more about distance and length.

However, take a look at this practise question:

> １９７２年、東京{とうきょう}から大阪{おおさか}までだった東海道{とうかいどう}新幹線{しんかんせん}は岡山{おかやま}まで____________。
>
> **A**　長引{ながひ}いた 　**B**　広{ひろ}がった 　**C**　延{の}びた 　**D**　伸{の}びた

I chose, **D**, because it was about length.

According to the book, though, the answer is **C**.

How can I make sense of this answer in light of the example sentences?

Comment: Not relevant in the least bit but my reputation is 3456 and yours is 5678 at this instant. Thought it was something interesting to share =D.

Comment: It's potentially the start of a Dan Brown novel... ;)

Comment: There are some `のびる` which can have both `伸びる` and `延びる`. `伸びる` is almost for *physical* stuff and the other is for *space and time*. An exception I know is `[金]{きん}を[叩]{たた}いて[延]{の}ばす`, which means `Beat out gold`. Also: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/172188/meaning/m0u/

Comment: Does it mean 伸 is preferred when the topic is animate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the Microsoft IME as a guide, generally 延びる seems to be used as "extend" and 伸びる as "grow":

**延びる:**

- Extend a conversation
- Extend a schedule
- Extend life span
- Extend a subway into the suburbs

**伸びる:**

- Plants/people grow
- Expand investigations (in relation to the law etc)
- Grow one's knowledge
- Grow a market/earnings

Answer (score 1):

According to [business-textbooks.com](https://business-textbooks.com/nobasu-difference/#toc-4)

> 延ばすのもう1つの意味としては、あるものに別のものをくっつけ、長さを足すというものがあります。具体的な物としては、延長コードがこれにあたります。こうした付着による長さの付け足しは、「伸ばす」には含まれませんから、この点は両者の違いとなっています。

So the instance of adding one thing's length to another to extend the total length uses 延, and this seems to match the case in question, that of extending tracks.